# SVD of (2,1,-2) not ok

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, orthogonality, orthonormal, svd

I'm trying to find the SVD of 
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
2&1&-2\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

I found $$\Sigma , u$$

But on the V matrix I got
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
-\frac{2}{3}&&\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&&\frac{-1}{\sqrt{5}} \\
-\frac{1}{3}&&0&&\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}} \\
\frac{2}{3}&&\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&&0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

While Wolfram Alpha gives : 
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otNrU.gif)

I checked the eigenvectors on wolfram alpha as well and they are correct:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
-2&&1&&-1\\
-1&&0&&2\\
2&&1&&0\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

I realized that the 3rd collumn of V (the one from wolfram alpha) is obtained by doing the cross product of the first two eigenvectors , why is that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [singular value decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) of a $1\times 3$ matrix can be written almost "by inspection":

$$ \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 & -2 \end{pmatrix} = U \Sigma V^* $$

where $U,V$ are unitary (in this case, orthogonal) matrices and $\Sigma$ is a rectangular diagonal matrix with the required singular values on the diagonal:

$$ \Sigma = \begin{pmatrix} \lambda & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} $$

Since $U$ is a $1\times 1$ unitary matrix, actually $U = (1)$ is just the $1\times 1$ identity.  $\Sigma$ is a $1\times 3$ matrix of equal Euclidean norm to $\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 & -2 \end{pmatrix}$, so $\Sigma = \begin{pmatrix} 3 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$.

The requirement that $V$ be unitary (or orthogonal) does not uniquely specify its entries.  So long as:

$$ \begin{pmatrix} 3 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} V^* = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 & -2 \end{pmatrix} $$

it will meet the definition of a singular value decomposition, and from this we see that only the first column of $V$ (top row of $V^*$) is determined:

$$ V^* = \begin{pmatrix} \frac{2}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & -\frac{2}{3} \\
{-} & {-} & {-} \\ {-} & {-} & {-} \end{pmatrix} $$

The bottom two rows of $V^*$ can be filled in with any pair of unit vectors that make up an orthonormal basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$ together with the top row shown.  Therefore it is not surprising that the third row might be the cross-product of the first two rows (since the third row will be determined, up to sign, by the first two rows).

Answer (score 2):

### Problem

Detailed instructions for computing the SVD abound on Math Stack Exchange. For example: [SVD and the columns](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2287795/svd-and-the-columns-i-did-this-wrong-but-it-seems-that-it-still-works-why/2297254#2297254), [SVD -obligation of normalization](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2251361/svd-obligation-of-normalization/2262637#2262637), [how SVD is calculated in reality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2252174/how-svd-is-calculated-in-reality/2262704#2262704), [Pseudo-inverse of a matrix that is neither fat nor tall?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1971211/pseudo-inverse-of-a-matrix-that-is-neither-fat-nor-tall/2181445#2181445).

This problem is straightforward. Let the target matrix be the covector
$$
\mathbf{A} = \left[ \begin{array}{ccr}
 2 & 1 & -2
\end{array} \right]
$$

Find the singular value decomposition
$$ 
 \mathbf{A} = \mathbf{U} \, \Sigma \, \mathbf{V}^{*}
$$

### Methods

The first link presents a table showing two paths for finding the SVD for a matrix $\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{C}^{m \times n}_{\rho}$:

$$
\begin{array}{lll}
%
 \text{Operation} &  
\text{Row space first} & \text{Column space first} \\\hline
%
  \text{1. Construct product matrix}  &
  \mathbf{W} = \mathbf{A}^{*} \mathbf{A} & 
  \mathbf{W} = \mathbf{A} \, \mathbf{A}^{*} \\
%
  \text{2. Solve for eigenvalues}  &
  \sigma = \tilde{\lambda} \left( \mathbf{W} \right) & 
  \sigma = \tilde{\lambda} \left( \mathbf{W} \right) \\
%
  \color{blue}{\text{3. Solve for eigenvectors }} w_{k},\  k=1, \rho  &
  \left( \mathbf{W} - \lambda_{k} \mathbf{I}_{n} \right) w_{k} = \mathbf{0} &
  \left( \mathbf{W} - \lambda_{k} \mathbf{I}_{m} \right) w_{k} = \mathbf{0} \\
%
  \text{4. Assemble domain matrix}  &
  \mathbf{V}_{k} = \frac{w_{k}}{\lVert w_{k} \rVert_{2}} &
  \mathbf{U}_{k} = \frac{w_{k}}{\lVert w_{k} \rVert_{2}} &
\\
%
  \text{5. Compute complementary domain matrix}  &
  \mathbf{U}_{k} = \sigma_{k}^{-1} \mathbf{A} \mathbf{V}_{k} &
  \mathbf{V}_{k} = \sigma_{k}^{-1} \mathbf{A}^{*} \mathbf{U}_{k} &
\\
%
\end{array}
$$

The two product matrices to wrok with are
$$
\mathbf{A} \mathbf{A}^{*} =
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
  9 \\
\end{array}
\right]
\qquad
\mathbf{A}^{*} \mathbf{A} =
\left[
\begin{array}{rrr}
  4 &  2 & -4 \\
  2 &  1 & -2 \\
 -4 & -2 &  4 \\
\end{array}
\right].
$$

### Solution

The product matrix $\mathbf{A} \mathbf{A}^{*}$ is much easier to work with!

**Singular values**

The eigenvalue is
$$
 \lambda \left( \mathbf{A}\mathbf{A}^{*} \right) = 9
$$
which implies the singular value is
$$
 \sigma = \sqrt{\lambda \left( \mathbf{A}\mathbf{A}^{*} \right)} = 3
$$
The matrix of singular values is
$$
 \mathbf{S} = 
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
  3 
\end{array}
\right]
$$
There is no need for $0$ padding, so
$$ 
 \Sigma = \mathbf{S}
$$

**Matrix** $\mathbf{U}$

The eigenvector is already normalized and represents the first column 
$$
\mathbf{U} =
\color{blue}{\left[
\begin{array}{c}
  1 
\end{array}
\right]}
$$

Coloring distinguishes $\color{blue}{range}$ space vectors from $\color{red}{null}$ space vectors.

*Column space*
$$
\begin{align}
 \color{blue}{\mathcal{R}\left(\mathbf{A}\right)} 
&=
\text{span} \left\{ \,
\color{blue}{\left[
\begin{array}{c}
  1 
\end{array}
\right]}
\, \right\} \\
%
 \color{red}{\mathcal{N}\left(\mathbf{A}^{*}\right)}  &= 
\left\{ 0 \right\}
\end{align}
$$

**Matrix** $\mathbf{V}$

$$
  \mathbf{V}_{1} 
= \frac{1}{\sigma} \mathbf{A}^{*} \mathbf{U}_{k}
= \frac{1}{3}
\color{blue}{\left[
\begin{array}{r}
  2 \\ 1 \\ -2 
\end{array}
\right]}
$$

For the $\color{red}{null}$ space vectors, we have options. We could call upon the process of Gram and Schmidt. Or we could eyeball the problem to find any $\color{red}{null}$ space vector, and use the cross product to find the missing vector.

Choosing the latter, we select 
$$
\color{red}{\mathbf{V}_{2}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\color{red}{\left[
\begin{array}{r}
  1 \\ 0 \\ 1 
\end{array}
\right]}
$$

The missing vector is then
$$
\color{blue}{\left[
\begin{array}{r}
  2 \\ 1 \\ -2 
\end{array}
\right]}
\times
\color{red}{\left[
\begin{array}{r}
  1 \\ 0 \\ 1 
\end{array}
\right]}
=
\color{red}{\left[
\begin{array}{r}
  1 \\ -4 \\ -1 
\end{array}
\right]}
$$

**Final assembly**
$$
\begin{align}
 \mathbf{A} &= \mathbf{U} \, \Sigma \mathbf{V}^{*}
% U
\\ &=
\color{blue}{\left[
\begin{array}{c}
  1 
\end{array}
\right]}
% Sigma
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
  3 
\end{array}
\right]
% V*
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
  % c1
\frac{1}{3}
\color{blue}{\left[
\begin{array}{r}
  2 \\ 1 \\ -2 
\end{array}
\right]}
  % c2
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\color{red}{\left[
\begin{array}{r}
  1 \\ 0 \\ 1 
\end{array}
\right]}
  % c3
\frac{1}{3\sqrt{2}}
\color{red}{\left[
\begin{array}{r}
  1 \\ -4 \\ -1 
\end{array}
\right]}
\end{array}
\right]
%
\\ &=
 \left[ \begin{array}{ccr}
 2 & 1 & -2
\end{array} \right]
%
\end{align}
$$