# how SVD is calculated in reality

Tags: svd

let us suppose that we have following matrix
$
       A=
      \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
       4 & 0 \\
       3 & -5 \\
      \end{array} } \right]
    $

for calculation of  SVD,first i have calculated $A'*A$   which is equal to

$
       A'*A=
      \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
       25 & -15 \\
       -15 & 25 \\
      \end{array} } \right]
    $

eigenvalues of this  matrix is equal to   $40$ and $10$,  eigenvector of  following matrix

$    
      \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
       -15 & -15 \\
       -15 & -15 \\
      \end{array} } \right]
    $

i got this matrix after subtraction of $40$ from diagonal elements, eigenvector is equal to
\begin{bmatrix}-1 \\ 1\\ \end{bmatrix}

after inserting of eigenvalues of $10$, i got  following matrix

$    
      \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
       15 & -15 \\
       -15 & 15 \\
      \end{array} } \right]
    $

eigenvector of this matrix is equal to

\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 1\\ \end{bmatrix}

so normalization of these  vectors and putting in  one matrix  $V$ will  have  the following  form

$    
      \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
       -1/\sqrt{2} & 1/\sqrt{2} \\
       1/\sqrt{2} & 1/\sqrt{2} \\
      \end{array} } \right]
    $

now i know that

$A*V=U*E$ where  $E$ is equal to

$    
      \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
       \sqrt{40} & 0 \\
       0 & \sqrt{10} \\
      \end{array} } \right]
    $

we know that

$A*v1=u1*\sigma$

let us try to multiply

$
       \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
       4 & 0 \\
       3 & -5 \\
      \end{array} } \right] 
    $ 
by

\begin{bmatrix}-1/\sqrt{2} \\ 1/\sqrt{2} \\ \end{bmatrix}

i got  the following result

\begin{bmatrix}-4/\sqrt{2} \\ -8/\sqrt{2} \\ \end{bmatrix}

but i can't get equation for  $\sigma$ and $u$  please help me

Comment: please any ideas? i am sure i am doing correctly, what is wrong with  that method ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did everything correctly. You already found $\sigma_1,\sigma_2$ - they are the square roots of the eigenvalues of $A^TA$ so $\sigma_1 = \sqrt{40},\sigma_2 = \sqrt{10}$. After you found $V$ with columns $v_1,v_2$, you must have

$$ Av_1 = \sigma_1 u_1, Av_2 = \sigma_2 u_2 $$

so $u_1$ is just $\frac{Av_1}{\sigma_1}$ and $u_2 = \frac{Av_2}{\sigma_2}$. In your case,

$$ u_1 = \begin{pmatrix} -\frac{4}{\sqrt{2}} \\ -\frac{8}{\sqrt{2}} \end{pmatrix} \frac{1}{\sqrt{40}} = \begin{pmatrix} -\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \\ -\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}} \end{pmatrix}, \\
u_2 = \begin{pmatrix} \frac{4}{\sqrt{2}} \\ -\frac{2}{\sqrt{2}} \end{pmatrix} \frac{1}{\sqrt{10}} = \begin{pmatrix} \frac{2}{\sqrt{5}} \\ -\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \end{pmatrix} $$

and indeed

$$ \begin{pmatrix} -\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} & -\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}} \\ \frac{2}{\sqrt{5}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 4 & 0 \\ 3 & -5\end{pmatrix}  \begin{pmatrix} -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}  \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} \sqrt{40} & 0 \\ 0 & \sqrt{10} \end{pmatrix}. $$

Answer (score 3):

**Big picture**

Every matrix $\mathbf{A}\in\mathbb{C}^{m\times n}_{\rho}$ has a singular value decomposition
$$
\begin{align}
  \mathbf{A} &=
  \mathbf{U} \, \Sigma \, \mathbf{V}^{*} \\
%
 &=
% U 
  \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
     \color{blue}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{R}}} & \color{red}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{N}}}
  \end{array} \right]  
% Sigma
  \left[ \begin{array}{cccc|cc}
     \sigma_{1} & 0 & \dots &  &   & \dots &  0 \\
     0 & \sigma_{2}  \\
     \vdots && \ddots \\
       & & & \sigma_{\rho} \\\hline
       & & & & 0 & \\
     \vdots &&&&&\ddots \\
     0 & & &   &   &  & 0 \\
  \end{array} \right]
% V 
  \left[ \begin{array}{c}
     \color{blue}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{R}}}^{*} \\ 
     \color{red}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{N}}}^{*}
  \end{array} \right]  \\
%
  & =
% U
   \left[ \begin{array}{cccccccc}
    \color{blue}{u_{1}} & \dots & \color{blue}{u_{\rho}} & \color{red}{u_{\rho+1}} & \dots & \color{red}{u_{n}}
  \end{array} \right]
% Sigma
  \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
     \mathbf{S}_{\rho\times \rho} & \mathbf{0} \\
     \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} 
  \end{array} \right]
% V
   \left[ \begin{array}{c}
    \color{blue}{v_{1}^{*}} \\ 
    \vdots \\
    \color{blue}{v_{\rho}^{*}} \\
    \color{red}{v_{\rho+1}^{*}} \\
    \vdots \\ 
    \color{red}{v_{n}^{*}}
  \end{array} \right]
%
\end{align}
$$
The four fundamental subspaces for $\mathbf{A}$ are resolved into an orthonormal basis:
$$
\begin{align} 
% R A
\color{blue}{\mathcal{R} \left( \mathbf{A} \right)} &=
\text{span} \left\{
 \color{blue}{u_{1}}, \dots , \color{blue}{u_{\rho}}
\right\} \\
% R A*
\color{blue}{\mathcal{R} \left( \mathbf{A}^{*} \right)} &=
\text{span} \left\{
 \color{blue}{v_{1}}, \dots , \color{blue}{v_{\rho}}
\right\} \\
% N A*
\color{red}{\mathcal{N} \left( \mathbf{A}^{*} \right)} &=
\text{span} \left\{
\color{red}{u_{\rho+1}}, \dots , \color{red}{u_{m}}
\right\} \\
% N A
\color{red}{\mathcal{N} \left( \mathbf{A} \right)} &=
\text{span} \left\{
\color{red}{v_{\rho+1}}, \dots , \color{red}{v_{n}}
\right\} \\
%
\end{align}
$$
Compute the SVD involves resolving the $\color{blue}{range} spaces$:

1. Resolve the domain $\mathbb{C}^{n}$ by finding eigenvectors of $\mathbf{A}^{*}\mathbf{A}$. Outputs: matrix of singular values $\mathbf{S}$, $\color{blue}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{R}}}$.
2. Resolve the domain $\mathbb{C}^{n}$ by computing $\color{blue}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{R}}}$ using $\mathbf{S}$ and  $\color{blue}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{R}}}$

---

**1. Resolve**  $\ \color{blue}{\mathcal{R} \left( \mathbf{A}^{*} \right)}$

*Step 1*:

Compute product matrix
$$
%
\begin{align}
%
 \mathbf{W} = \mathbf{A}^{T}\mathbf{A} = 
% At
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
 4 & 0 \\
 3 & 5 \\
\end{array}
\right]
% A
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
 4 & 3 \\
 0 & 5 \\
\end{array}
\right]
%
=
%
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
 25 & 15 \\
 15 & 25 \\
\end{array}
\right]
%
\end{align}
%
$$

*Step 2*:

Compute eigenvalue spectrum $\lambda \left(\mathbf{W}\right)$

$$
 \det \mathbf{W} = 400, \qquad \text{trace } \mathbf{W} = 50
$$
The characteristic polynomial is
$$
 p(\lambda) = \lambda^{2} - \lambda \text{ trace } \mathbf{W} + \det \mathbf{W}
= \lambda ^2-50 \lambda +400 = 
\left( \lambda - 40 \right) \left( \lambda - 10 \right)
$$
The roots of the $p(\lambda)$ are the eigenvalues of $\mathbf{W}$:
$$
 \lambda \left(\mathbf{W}\right) = \left\{ 40, 10 \right\}
$$

*Step 3*:

Compute singular value spectrum $\sigma$

To obtain the singular values: form $\tilde{\lambda}$, a list arranged in decreasing order with $0$ values culled:
$$
 \sigma = \sqrt{\tilde{\lambda}} = \left\{ 2 \sqrt{10},\sqrt{10} \right\}
$$
The singular values are the diagonal entries of the $\mathbf{S}$:
$$
\boxed{
 \mathbf{S} = \sqrt{10}\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
 2  & 0 \\
 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
}
$$

*Step 4*:

Compute eigenvectors of $\mathbf{W}$

Fundamental tool: eigenvalue equation
$$
  \mathbf{W} v_{k} = \lambda_{k} v_{k}, \qquad k = 1, 2
$$

$k=1$:
$$
%
\begin{align}
%
 \mathbf{W} v_{1} &= \lambda_{1} v_{1} \\
%
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
 25 & 15 \\
 15 & 25 \\
\end{array}
\right]
%
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
 x \\ y \\
\end{array}
\right]
%
&=
%
8
%
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
 x \\ y \\
\end{array}
\right] \\[3pt]
% % %
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
 25 x + 15 y \\ 15 x + 25 y \\
\end{array}
\right]
&=
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
 40x \\ 40y \\
\end{array}
\right]\\[3pt]
% % %
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
 x \\ y \\
\end{array}
\right]
&=
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
 1 \\ 1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
%
\end{align}
%
$$
The normalized vector is the first column vector in $\color{blue}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{R}}}$.
$$
  \hat{v}_{1} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\left[
\begin{array}{r}
 1 \\ 1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

$k=2$:
$$
%
\begin{align}
%
 \mathbf{W} v_{2} &= \lambda_{2} v_{2} \\
%
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
 25 & 15 \\
 15 & 25 \\
\end{array}
\right]
%
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
 x \\ y \\
\end{array}
\right]
%
&=
%
10
%
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
 x \\ y \\
\end{array}
\right] \\[3pt]
% % %
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
 25 x + 15 y \\ 15 x + 25 y \\
\end{array}
\right]
&=
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
 10x \\ 10y \\
\end{array}
\right]\\[3pt]
% % %
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
 x \\ y \\
\end{array}
\right]
&=
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
 -1 \\ 1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
%
\end{align}
%
$$
The normalized vector is the second column vector in $\color{blue}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{R}}}$.
$$
  \hat{v}_{2} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\left[
\begin{array}{r}
 -1 \\ 1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$
Assemble:
$$
\boxed{
\color{blue}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{R}}} =  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
%
\left[
\begin{array}{cr}
 1 & -1 \\
 1 &  1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
}
$$

**2. Resolve**  $\ \color{blue}{\mathcal{R} \left( \mathbf{A} \right)}$

Rearrange the definition of the SVD  (1) to recover
$$
 \color{blue}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{R}}} = \mathbf{A} \,  \color{blue}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{R}}}  \, \mathbf{S}^{-1}
$$

Compute directly:
$$
\begin{align}
  \color{blue}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{R}}} =
\mathbf{A} \color{blue}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{R}}} \mathbf{S}^{-1}
%
&=
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
 4 & 0 \\
 3 & 5 \\
\end{array}
\right]
%
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\left[
\begin{array}{cr}
 1 & -1 \\
 1 &  1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
% Sinv
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{10}} & 0 \\
 0 & \frac{1}{\sqrt{10}} \\
\end{array}
\right]
%
\end{align}
%
$$
At last,
$$
\boxed{
\color{blue}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{R}}} = 
\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}
\left[
\begin{array}{cr}
  1 & -2 \\
 2 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
}
$$

---

**Final answer**

$$
  \mathbf{A} = 
\color{blue}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{R}}} 
\mathbf{S} 
\color{blue}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{R}}}^{*} =
%
\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}
\left[
\begin{array}{cr}
  1 & -2 \\
 2 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
%
 \sqrt{10}
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
  20 & 0 \\
  0 & 10 \\
\end{array}
\right]
% S
%
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\left[
\begin{array}{cr}
 1 & -1 \\
 1 &  1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
%
=
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
 4 & 0 \\
 3 & 5 \\
\end{array}
\right]
%
$$